# Java : Proto parser library

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protocols, protoc

I want to parse a proto file. Wanted to check is there any java library available which can parse proto files. Based on my requirement I **cannot use** **descriptor parseFrom method** or **protoc command**. Please suggest thanks in advance.

```
$ protoc --include_imports --descriptor_set_out temp *.proto // I don't want to do this manual step 
or 
DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorProto descriptorProto = DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorProto.parseFrom(proto.getBytes());
```

Appreciate suggestion thanks

Comment: Could you clarify *why* you don't want to run the tool that is designed to give you exactly what you're looking for? (I can think of various *potential* reasons, but your *specific* reason would affect possible solutions.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet- It is because I want to run this step in jenkins and we are not allowed to make any configuration changes there.

Comment: I would talk to the people who set those rules then. Requiring that no tools are available other than Java seems overly prohibitive to me. (Would you expect that "something equivalent to protoc" is available in *every* language just in case there's someone else with that requirement but for PHP, Ruby etc?)

Comment: @JonSkeet with multiple Jenkins workers, it can get cumbersome to have to install several tools. You could use tools like Puppet to do so, but if one tool is allowed, then others will ask for tools as well, and you end up with a system full of tools used for just one or two jobs.

Whenever I want to do something in Jenkins that requires extra tools I try to find (or create) a Docker container, then run that. That way, only one tool (Docker) is needed. A quick Google search showed several candidates.

Comment: @RobSpoor: Putting together a Docker container of useful tools or finding an existing one seems reasonable. Requiring that every possible tool is written in every language is not, IMO :)

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree.

Comment: When you say "parse a proto file", what do you mean - parse it into what exactly? Parsers typically produce an AST representation of the input - is that what you want?

Comment: @Maana, what build system do you use? Maven, Gradle, etc.? There are the corresponding build system plugins (`protobuf-maven-plugin`, `protobuf-gradle-plugin`) that generate the code as a part of the build process. Would using such a build system plugin be an acceptable solution for you?

Comment: @jon-hanson
So, I writing a sonarqube custome plugin in java which will scan any application(java, go etc) and look for .proto file and parse it. I want that parser to give back details about all messages, fieldTypes etc..

Comment: @Sergey Vyacheslavovich Brunov- I am writing sonarqube custom proto parser so I should be able to scan any application java or golang and read the proto file. The thing with generated code is that it is not consistent across different languages. In java we get .class file where in go we get pb.go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Possible solution: `io.protostuff:protostuff-parser` library

Let's consider the `3.1.38` version of the `io.protostuff:protostuff-parser` library as the current version.

- Maven dependency: [Maven Repository: io.protostuff » protostuff-parser » 3.1.38](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.protostuff/protostuff-parser/3.1.38).
- `protostuff-parser` Maven module directory in GitHub repository: [protostuff-compiler/protostuff-parser at v3.1.38 · protostuff/protostuff-compiler](https://github.com/protostuff/protostuff-compiler/tree/v3.1.38/protostuff-parser).
- GitHub repository: [protostuff/protostuff-compiler at v3.1.38](https://github.com/protostuff/protostuff-compiler/tree/v3.1.38).

### Example program

Please, consider the below example program as **a draft** to get started with the library.

#### Input file

Let's assume the `/some/directory/data/test.proto` file exist with the following content:

```proto
message SearchRequest {
  string query = 1;
  int32 page_number = 2;
  int32 result_per_page = 3;
  enum ContentType {
    WEB = 1;
    IMAGES = 2;
    VIDEO = 3;
  }
  ContentType content_type = 4;
}
```

#### `pom.xml`: Dependencies

```xml
<project>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.protostuff</groupId>
            <artifactId>protostuff-parser</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

#### Program

```java
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import io.protostuff.compiler.ParserModule;
import io.protostuff.compiler.model.Message;
import io.protostuff.compiler.model.Proto;
import io.protostuff.compiler.parser.Importer;
import io.protostuff.compiler.parser.LocalFileReader;
import io.protostuff.compiler.parser.ProtoContext;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.List;

public final class Program {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ParserModule());
        final Importer importer = injector.getInstance(Importer.class);
        final ProtoContext protoContext = importer.importFile(
            new LocalFileReader(Path.of("/some/directory/data")),
            "test.proto"
        );

        final Proto proto = protoContext.getProto();

        final List<Message> messages = proto.getMessages();
        System.out.println(String.format("Messages: %s", messages));

        final Message searchRequestMessage = proto.getMessage("SearchRequest");
        System.out.println(String.format("SearchRequest message: %s", searchRequestMessage));

        final List<Enum> searchRequestMessageEnums = searchRequestMessage.getEnums();
        System.out.println(String.format("SearchRequest message enums: %s", searchRequestMessageEnums));
    }
}
```

The program output:

```
Messages: [Message{name=SearchRequest, fullyQualifiedName=..SearchRequest, fields=[Field{name=query, typeName=string, tag=1, options=DynamicMessage{fields={}}}, Field{name=page_number, typeName=int32, tag=2, options=DynamicMessage{fields={}}}, Field{name=result_per_page, typeName=int32, tag=3, options=DynamicMessage{fields={}}}, Field{name=content_type, typeName=ContentType, tag=4, options=DynamicMessage{fields={}}}], enums=[Enum{name=ContentType, fullyQualifiedName=..SearchRequest.ContentType, constants=[EnumConstant{name=WEB, value=1, options=DynamicMessage{fields={}}}, EnumConstant{name=IMAGES, value=2, options=DynamicMessage{fields={}}}, EnumConstant{name=VIDEO, value=3, options=DynamicMessage{fields={}}}], options=DynamicMessage{fields={}}}], options=DynamicMessage{fields={}}}]
SearchRequest message: Message{name=SearchRequest, fullyQualifiedName=..SearchRequest, fields=[Field{name=query, typeName=string, tag=1, options=DynamicMessage{fields={}}}, Field{name=page_number, typeName=int32, tag=2, options=DynamicMessage{fields={}}}, Field{name=result_per_page, typeName=int32, tag=3, options=DynamicMessage{fields={}}}, Field{name=content_type, typeName=ContentType, tag=4, options=DynamicMessage{fields={}}}], enums=[Enum{name=ContentType, fullyQualifiedName=..SearchRequest.ContentType, constants=[EnumConstant{name=WEB, value=1, options=DynamicMessage{fields={}}}, EnumConstant{name=IMAGES, value=2, options=DynamicMessage{fields={}}}, EnumConstant{name=VIDEO, value=3, options=DynamicMessage{fields={}}}], options=DynamicMessage{fields={}}}], options=DynamicMessage{fields={}}}
SearchRequest message enums: [Enum{name=ContentType, fullyQualifiedName=..SearchRequest.ContentType, constants=[EnumConstant{name=WEB, value=1, options=DynamicMessage{fields={}}}, EnumConstant{name=IMAGES, value=2, options=DynamicMessage{fields={}}}, EnumConstant{name=VIDEO, value=3, options=DynamicMessage{fields={}}}], options=DynamicMessage{fields={}}}]
```

Comment: Thank you Sergey Vyacheslavovich Brunov this is what I was looking for :)

Comment: Sergey Vyacheslavovich Brunov : Any idea on how to resolve import. If import is not found I am getting error like - Can not load proto: google.protobuf.descriptor.proto not found.

Comment: @Maana, that is another question. Please, consider asking it as a separate question (not a comment) with the corresponding minimal reproducible example.